# Search bar with dropdown catagories. Search results not pulling from database and showing

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have search bar that I'm hoping searches records in a mysql database and show them on a webpage. It should allow the user to choose the field they are searching under but it is is not showing the records the other end. Any ideas?

html:

```html
 <form action='recordresult.php' method='POST' name='form_filter' class="form-style-1" >    
    <b>Search</b><br>
    <select name="selectVal">
        <option value="category" >Select a category</option>
<option value="first_name">First Name</option>
<option value="surname">Surname</option>
<option value="address">Address</option>
<option value="phonenumber">Telephone</option>
    </select>
    <input type='text' name='search' placeholder='Enter text here...'><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Send'>  
</form>
```

PHP

```html
<?php
include("config.php");
$link = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass)
or die ("Could not connect to mysql because ".mysqli_error($link));

// select the database
mysqli_select_db($link, $database)
or die ("Could not select database because ".mysqli_error($link));

  $search         = isset($_POST['search'])       ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['search']))      : null;
    $catLocation    = isset($_POST['selectVal'])    ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['selectVal']))   : null;
    $query          = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ";

    //YOU INDICATED YOU'D NEED TO RUN THE SEARCH-QUERY IF THE SEARCH-TERM AND SEARCH-SCOPE ARE DEFINED IE: NOT NULL; HOWEVER IF THE SEARCH TERM IS NOT GIVEN, YOU SELECT EVERYTHING IN THAT TABLE... (BAD PRACTICE, THOUGH)
    if($catLocation){
        if($search){
            if($catLocation == "category"){
                $query .= " category LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
            }
   else if($catLocation == "first_name"){
                $query .=  "first_name LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
            }
   else if($catLocation == "surname"){
                $query .=  "surname LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
            }
   else if($catLocation == "address"){
                $query .=  "address LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
            }
   else if($catLocation == "phonenumber"){
                $query .=  "phonenumber LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
            }
        }
  
  else{
            $query .= "1";            
        }

        $sql        = mysqli_query($query);
        //HERE AGAIN WAS AN ERROR... YOU PASSED mysql_fetch_array A STRING $query INSTEAD OF A RESOURCE: $sql
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            $firstname  = $row["first_name"];
            $surname    = $row["surname"];
            $address   = $row["address"];
            $phonenumber = $row['phonenumber'];
            

            echo "First Name :  $firstname<br>";
            echo "Surname : $surname<br>";
            echo "Address : $address<br>";
            echo "Phone Number: $phonenumber<br>";
          
        }

    }
 
?>
```

The code doesn't provide any errors just a blank area where it should be. Also wondering if anyone know if it's possible to have first_name and surname as fields and search say "Emma Watson" and to be able to return results from both fields if one of the words are in there?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: where are you declaring $table? Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below updated code

```
include("config.php");
$link = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("Could not connect to mysql because ".mysqli_error($link));

// select the database
mysqli_select_db($link, $database)
or die ("Could not select database because ".mysqli_error($link));

$search         = isset($_POST['search'])       ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['search']))      : null;
$catLocation    = isset($_POST['selectVal'])    ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['selectVal']))   : null;
$query          = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ";

//**If you want to merge for first name and surname then you need to merge both query with OR condition as below**
if($catLocation){
    if($search){
        if($catLocation == "category"){
            $query .= " category LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
        }
        else if($catLocation == "name"){
            $query .=  " ( first_name LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR surname LIKE '%" . $search . "%' ) ";
        }
        else if($catLocation == "address"){
            $query .=  "address LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
        }
        else if($catLocation == "phonenumber"){
            $query .=  "phonenumber LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
        }
    }   
    else{
        $query .= "1";            
    }

    $sql = mysqli_query($link, $query); // **Adding reference connection variable**

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $firstname  = $row["first_name"];
        $surname    = $row["surname"];
        $address   = $row["address"];
        $phonenumber = $row['phonenumber'];


        echo "First Name :  $firstname<br>";
        echo "Surname : $surname<br>";
        echo "Address : $address<br>";
        echo "Phone Number: $phonenumber<br>";

    }

}
```

**Merge 2 fields (Firstname and surname) in single (name) for search in both fields**

```
<form action='recordresult.php' method='POST' name='form_filter' class="form-style-1" >    
<b>Search</b><br>
<select name="selectVal">
    <option value="category" >Select a category</option>
    <option value="name">name</option>
    <option value="address">Address</option>
    <option value="phonenumber">Telephone</option>
</select>
<input type='text' name='search' placeholder='Enter text here...'><br>
<input type='submit' value='Send'>  
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! See my reply above :)

Comment: @natstv - Add error_reporting(-1) top of your code. Also, before execution of query, print it on page and run it in phpmyadmin

Comment: Hey. Thank you for all your help, I got it working after looking at errors and making it much more simple. Thanks again for all your help!